# Created new instance from AMIs but Status Checks error "1/2 checks passed"

Tags: amazon-ec2

I have a production environment running Ubuntu 18.04 LTS on an EC2 instance type t3.xlarge

Since I need more compute power for my App, I have decided to duplicate the current instance by creating a more powerful new instance as follows:

1. Created an image of the Production EC2 (Note: I selected "No reboot"
   in order not to reboot the Production instance)
2. Launched a new an instance by selecting instance type c5.4xlarge

After successfully launching the new instance, the Status Checks for about 10 minutes was "Initializing" and then changed to "1/2 checks passed" and can not access to the new instance

[I have put the system log file here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/v5271ehzesjrg35/system%20log.txt?dl=0)

Comment: Can you change the new instance back to a `t3.xlarge` just to see whether it starts successfully? Then, try flicking it back to `c5.4xlarge` and see whether it works. The second [status check](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/monitoring-system-instance-status-check.html) checks things like kernels, so it might be an incompatibility between the OS and the CPU.

Comment: I tried back to t3.xlarge but still the same issue.

Comment: Also status check shows : 

Instance reachability check failed at March 2, 2020 at 7:34:00 AM UTC+3 (17 minutes ago)

If you are having problems with this instance, you can try one of the following options to resolve it:
Reboot this instance.
Modify your operating system configuration.
Terminate this instance and launch a replacement.

Comment: I would suggest you launch a new `t3.xlarge` with the AMI and see if it just magically works. If not, then something would seem strange with the AMI.

Comment: @John Rotenstein I did launched a new t3.xlarge instance but still the same issue happened. When I took this AMI image I did not mark the reboot option.  I do not know if this is the issue?

Comment: By selecting "No Reboot", the boot disk is immediately copied without an OS shutdown. This _might_ leave the disk in an inconsistent state. It would be similar to pulling the power cord out of a computer and turning it on again. If possible, I would suggest creating another AMI without "No Reboot" (so that it _does_ reboot). You will likely need to do this during your quiet/maintenance period.

Comment: I tried taking an image by NOT selecting "No Reboot" but still I am facing the same issue

Comment: Maybe: [Troubleshooting Instances with Failed Status Checks - Amazon EC2](https://docs.amazonaws.cn/en_us/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/TroubleshootingInstances.html)